# Any programs or scripts that will add size prefix (u8, u16 and etc) to C variable name

Tags: c

As an embedded software engineer, I am required to add a size prefix (u8, u16 and etc) to variable names.  Has anyone created or know of a program that will do that automatically?

Comment: Why would you add those to the variable name when you could just use types from `stdint.h` ?

Comment: You say you are "required" to do this.  By what/whom?

Comment: John: coding standards. I realize the size prefix seems redundant when you could just look at the variable definition, however, it makes the code more explicit and allows other programmer reviewing the code to find coding errors that would cause overflows.

Eric: the prefix are different from the type definition.

Comment: You might be able to make such a tool out of `clang`. But I'm not sure it's worth the effort. I'd rather use smaller functions and declare variables close to where they are used so at the review time one can easily see the declared type.

Comment: if you _do_ do this, I would make each one more like u8___varname, so that it is unique enough to go back to sanity.  sed should be sufficient if you have the list of variables and types. (you didn't really say enough to tell)  on the plus side if you know the type you need, your editor will be more helpful in suggesting proper completions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. Don't ever *think* of doing it.

Your `uint16` of today can very well be `uint32` for efficiency in a few year's time on the next architecture. Then the "helpful prefix" will just be confusing. If you want that kind of information, grab something like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) or ask your IDE about the type of the variable, when required. Don't waste the (we all know *very* limited!) brain bandwidth of the programmer with (most of the time) irrelevant details.

Also check out the Linux [CodingStyle](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/CodingStyle) for more thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I also don't like that style of naming, but *code validation* is an important thing for certain softwares (were danger to users can be present). In such a context, changing from uint16 to uint32 is a modification that has to be validated again, so it is not a problem.

Comment: Think, also, that code validation is made by independent inspectors, that can superimpose unwanted techniques, but they are in command...